redis does not terminate correctly in python script
Exception ignored in: <function AbstractConnection.del at 0x7f885f8334c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 216, in del
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 223, in _close
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/streams.py", line 358, in close
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 116, in close
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 624, in _start_shutdown
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 728, in call_later
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 741, in call_at
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 520, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
After updating the redis version from redis==4.3.3 to redis==5.0.3,
I changed the redis import to something like this:
import redis.asyncio as redis
Then the following error appears after running my script

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you ever resolve this?
